Title: How to Override Logback's DBAppender Tables and Use Custom Tables for Logging?
I am trying to customize the DBAppender class in Logback to use my own database tables for logging instead of the default ones(LOGGING_EVENT, LOGGING_EVENT_PROPERTY, and LOGGING_EVENT_EXCEPTION). Specifically, I want to define custom tables and columns and configure Logback to use these tables for storing log entries.
Logback Configuration: I’ve tried to configure the DBAppender in the logback.xml to use these custom tables, but it seems that my custom tables and SQL statements are being ignored.
14:32:17,979 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Ignoring unknown property [sqlStatements] in [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]. Anyway i have to define my values to be populated in this table. That is another step. Trying to complete this and proceed further.
Tried with customDB
<!-- Define Console Appender -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- H2 Database Appender Configuration -->
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
    <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
        <!-- H2 Driver class -->
        <driverClass>org.h2.Driver</driverClass>
        
        <!-- H2 JDBC URL for in-memory database -->
        <url>jdbc:h2:mem:logdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</url>
        
        <!-- H2 username and password (default values) -->
        <user>sa</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </connectionSource>
    
    <!-- Specify the custom DBNameResolver -->
    <dbNameResolver class="com.example.config.MyDBNameResolver" />    

    <!-- Configure the SQL for creating tables if needed -->
    <sqlStatements>
        <!-- SQL to create the table if it does not exist -->
        <createTable>
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS custom_log_table (
                log_timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                log_level VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                log_logger VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                log_message TEXT NOT NULL
            )
        </createTable>
        
        <!-- SQL to drop the table if needed (use cautiously) -->
        <dropTable>
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS custom_log_table
        </dropTable>
        
        <!-- SQL to insert log entries into the table -->
        <insertSQL>
            INSERT INTO custom_log_table (log_timestamp, log_level, log_logger, log_message)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        </insertSQL>
    </sqlStatements>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="DB" />
</root>

,
I tried with
    <!-- Specify the custom DBNameResolver -->
    <dbNameResolver class="com.example.config.MyDBNameResolver" />    

Define the class,
package com.example.config;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.db.names.DBNameResolver;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.db.names.ColumnName;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class MyDBNameResolver implements DBNameResolver {
// Map to store custom column names
private static final Map<ColumnName, String> columnNameMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
    columnNameMap.put(ColumnName.TIMESTAMP, "log_timestamp");
    columnNameMap.put(ColumnName.LEVEL, "log_level");
    columnNameMap.put(ColumnName.LOGGER_NAME, "log_logger");
    columnNameMap.put(ColumnName.MESSAGE, "log_message");
}

@Override
public String getTableName() {
    // Return the name of the table where logs should be inserted
    return "custom_log_table";
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(ColumnName columnName) {
    // Return the column name for the given ColumnName enum
    return columnNameMap.get(columnName);
}

}
but got an error,
error: MyDBNameResolver is not abstract and does not override abstract method getColumnName(N) in DBNameResolver
